# What is this flat, green, nettle-like shrub from Tenerife, Canary Islands?

Tags: identification, shrubs

What is this shrub that's low to the ground and looks flat, green, and nettle-like? It seems to thrive on lava fields and develops lignified stems.

It can be found around `28.266°,-16.588°` in [Teide National Park](https://www.volcanoteide.com/en/national_park) on [Tenerife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife) of the Canaries.

[image: image of the plant described above]
*(Click to see full-screen image for details.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a **Canary mountain figwort (Scrophularia glabrata)**.

[Wikimedia](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Scrophularia_glabrata#) has some photos for comparison, but I found a very nice one [here](https://tenerifenaturewalks.wordpress.com/tag/scrophularia-glabrata/):

[image]

Compare the leaves and seed heads to those in your photo.

According to the [Tenerife Tourism Corporation](http://www.webtenerife.co.uk/what-see/teide-national-park/flora+del+teide.htm#prettyPhoto) it's one if the top ten plants in the Teide National Park.

Comment: Great, this seems to be it, thanks! But like [the related question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/29827/), it looks quite diverse on different pictures and, also like *Erysimum scoparium*, there’s not too much information on *S. glabrata*.