# What is this pale mint green shrub with hay-colored booms from Tenerife, Canary Islands?

Tags: identification, shrubs

What is this pale mint green shrub that has hay-colored booms? It seems to thrive on lava fields and develops lignified stems.

It can be found around `28.266°,-16.588°` in [Teide National Park](https://www.volcanoteide.com/en/national_park) on [Tenerife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife) of the Canary Islands.

---

**EDIT**: With the plant having been [identified](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/29967/14139) below as ***Erysimum scoparium***, I have to add that the following pictures were taken on 2016-11-06 (i.e. November). There was no florescence, so the plants lacked their mauve, pale purple blossoms (see [Commons gallery](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Erysimum_scoparium)).

---

[image: image of the plant described above]
[image: image of the plant described above]
*(Click to see full-screen image for details.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [Erysimum scoparium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erysimum), (alhelí del Teide, Canary Islands' Wallflower). It's an endemic plant to the Islands and found at higher altitutes there.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Fantastic, this seems to be it, although it is somwhat unresembling when in bloom; I took the picture in November and it looks rather meager. Lots of photographs depict its obvious variety. Being endemic to this particular area adds to its beauty. Must be an amazing view when the lava field is covered in purple flowerage. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This one is a bit puzzling - the leaves and stems strongly resemble a plant which does grow freely in that region - Euphorbia balsamifera. However, the long, dried flowered stems do not - if you're 100% certain the dried stems belong to the shrub, and aren't simply something else growing up through it, then this ID is incorrect. Image and details are [here](http://www.redjaen.es/francis/?m=c&o=58982&letra=&ord=&id=58983). Note: the site is written in Spanish.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I’d wish that was the one, but it’s not. I added another picture showing a separate plant, and we can be sure there is no match. Thanks anyway. Also, too bad you rejected [my suggested edit](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12982).

Comment: @dakab - well it was worth a try. As for the edit, I couldn't see it made material difference to my original response, so in my judgement, it's not really a 'pity'...

Comment: The edit merely comprised proper use of hyphens. Apart from scientific names being usually set italic, the typogrphic changes were solely supposed to subliminally improve flow of reading.

Comment: @dakab Ah well, its my habit to use a dash (rather than its proper use as a hyphen) between phrases at times,but the matter of 'flow' isn't a material change, and I was happy with the flow as it stood.

Comment: Hi Bamboo! I don't know if you meant to link to a Spanish website, or if it redirected from a site that was previously in English. Obviously it doesn't change the pictures, but I added a note to people that the text is written in Spanish!

Comment: @Sue yea it was intentional because it was a good pic... google translates if anyone wanted to read it, not that it matters, its not the right plant anyway

Comment: I didn't realize Google would translate. I've never known how to do it!

Comment: @Sue - really? Google offers it up automatically on all my devices, both Android and Windows, it pops up as a window at the bottom of the page, giving you the choice to translate or not